How to change the colors in the code sections in Github Copilot in Visual Studio?
How to change the colors in the code sections in Github Copilot in Visual Studio?
The code shows as below and it's hard to read because of the poor contrast. I am using Visual Studio 2022 17.9.6 and 17.10 preview 6. I am using the dark theme.
I went through all the colors in Options -> Environments -> Fonts and Colors and didn't find it.

